# Нужна ли запятая, закрывающая оборот с "как"?

Tags: запятые, как

> Такие качества, как любовь, доброта и милосердие являются самыми главными чертами характера человека.

Нужна ли запятая после слова “милосердие”? Если нет, то почему?

Comment: Всего лишь интонационная пауза.

Comment: Пауза - это элемент интонации, то есть любая пауза является интонационной. Другое дело, что не каждая пауза обозначается знаком препинания ( он должен иметь грамматическое обоснование).  Так Вы не видите в ответе такого обоснования?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартный вариант оформления предложений  вида ТАКОЙ, КАК:

(1) *Такие качества, как любовь, доброта и милосердие, являются самыми главными чертами характера человека.*

Это простое предложение, осложненное **обособленным однородным рядом,** раскрывающим содержание определяемого сочетания "такие качества".

Это же предложение можно представить **в другой форме**:

(2) *Такие качества: любовь, доброта и милосердие — являются самыми главными чертами характера человека*. Однородный ряд с обобщающим словом.

(3) *Такие качества — любовь, доброта и милосердие — являются самыми главными чертами характера человека.* Однородный ряд с обобщающим словом или обособленный ряд приложений.

Как мы видим, **во всех случаях ряд является обособленным**, только для обособления применяются разные знаки.

Так что не "всего лишь интонационная пауза".

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна.

**Такие качества, как любовь, доброта и милосердие, являются самыми главными чертами характера человека.**

> [ТАКОЙ (,) КАК, местоимение + союз](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722)
>
> По общему правилу, обороты с союзом «как» выделяются запятыми, если в основной части предложения имеется указательное слово «такой».
>
> Быть может, только такие люди, как Шиллер, могли быть достойны ее любви. К. Паустовский, Такие, как ты, рождались во все эпохи кровавой истории наших планет. А. и Б. Стругацкие, Трудно быть богом.

Из Нацкорпуса:

> Естественно предположить, что такие типологические качества, как доминантность и подчиненность, являются врожденными, то есть, грубо говоря, что вожаками и подчиненными не становятся, а рождаются. [Борис Стариков. Кто круче — и почему? // «Знание-сила», 2012]

Comment: Знаю, что отвечаю довольно-таки поздно, но мой учитель категорически не согласен с запятой после слова "милосердие".